# Exclude regular expression from virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a virtual host in apache which is redirecting requests to another web server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName another.host
    ProxyPass        /  http://another.host2:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://another.host2:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to exclude an URL pattern from being catch by this virtual host. Basically I don't want requests with the url: http://another.host:8081/~username to be forwarded to the other server.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

No in that you cannot exclude something from matching the VirtualHost; anything that matches the host name will always be attached to that VirtualHost.

Yes in that you can get the behavior you want, by having your `ProxyPass` happen only in locations that you don't want to serve locally.

Try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName another.host
    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>
    <LocationMatch "^/[^~]">
        ProxyPass        /  http://another.host2:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse /  http://another.host2:8081/
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I completely understand the solution and agree with it. My problem is now that the expression in the LocationMatch is not being treated as a regular expression. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Joao Well, I had screwed up the regex; I had it trying to match the `~username` directories for proxying, instead of ignoring them.  I've edited the answer, try now?